# List of links with AJAX parsing data and changing class

Tags: php, ajax

I have been trying a lot of different ways to make this work, but haven't found the right way to tackle this yet.

I need to make a list of links, each containing a number of querystrings with data. I need this data going to "get.php" through AJAX. Apart from using the data in "get.php" I would like to be able to via PHP change the class of the specific link clicked - for an example from "noshow" to "inattendance" or a third option link "sick".

I am thinking of listing the links like this:

```
<a href="get.php?athlete=57&session=142" class="noshow">Athlete 1</a>
<a href="get.php?athlete=45&session=142" class="noshow">Athlete 2</a>
<a href="get.php?athlete=23&session=142" class="noshow">Athlete 3</a>
```

Or perhaps the data should be in the ID to better be recognized in the script?:

```
<a href="#" id="57&142" class="noshow">Athlete 1</a>
<a href="#" id="45&142" class="noshow">Athlete 2</a>
<a href="#" id="23&142" class="noshow">Athlete 3</a>
```

Is AJAX able to change a link based on its ID, or would each link need to be inside a DIV?

I would love to get some help regarding where to go from here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried and what you would expect the outcome to be.

Comment: Well I must have tried 10-20 different AJAX examples and tried to copy-paste my way to a solution, but every time something stops working at some point - My guess is that i'm probably trying to use a completely wrong approach. My question is how to approach this in the right manner.

Comment: Questions about approach are typically not well suited for SO - [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

1. Capture the click function
2. Create a reference to the element that triggered the click
3. Perform the ajax, and replace the url with the href of the element we clicked
4. Set the response type as JSON (so it is automatically parsed in the success function)
5. Compare if the class property has a null response, if not, add the class returned from the script

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the default action from taking you to get.php
        var $this = $(this); //cachable reference because $(this) inside the $.ajax() does not refer to the "A" we clicked on
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.prop("href"), //will pass the data, default is $_GET anyway
            dataType: 'json', //so we can easily access the class (if we need) and then the raw data.
            success: function(data){
                if(data.class != null){
                     $this.addClass(data.class); //add the class from the php script return
                }
                //do something with data.body which is the rest of the code
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then in your PHP script, just return a json array with the expected keys.

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'class' => 'inactive',
    'body' => 'whatever you were returning before'
));
```

Comment: Thanks! Same question for you - I must admit that JSON is completely new to me. When I try your code, the link is just sending me to get.php. Is there anything I should change in the code for it to work?

Comment: @Ypsala I've modified the code. I've gone ahead and added `e.preventDefault();` which will stop the link from following through to the new page, and allow the execution of the AJAX code to work proper. Please notice the `function(e)` as we've added the `(e)` as well, which passes the event object to the callback function so we can apply the `preventDefault()` method against it.

Comment: I just tried the code you wrote - same result. As I mentioned, I am completely new to terms like JSON and haven't worked with AJAX before, so I might be missing something obvious. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ypsala `$.ajax()` requires the use of the `jQuery library`, do you have `jQuery` installed?

Comment: I have the following included inside the <head> part:
'<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>' The code is running here: [link](http://a6-swim.dk/kontrol/test.html)

Comment: @Ypsala Check the console for errors. I don't think that I have any errors in my text, but, yeah.

Comment: The only error I can find in the console is regarding character encoding. The code is running here - maybe that helps? [link](http://a6-swim.dk/kontrol/test.html)

Comment: @Ypsala Please enclose my code within `$(function(){ //my code });` as you're not binding to the document ready handler currently, and the code cannot attach to elements that dont' exist at page load (when you are currently executing). Please see the updated code.

Comment: Thanks! Now the links are not going anywhere, which is good. I tried to add a javascript alert in the get.php to check whether or not the page is actually called or not. It doesnt open the alert, and nothing else happens. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ypsala You can't execute javascript like that through an ajax request. `console.log(data);` inside of `success: function(data){` and then check the console. You will see the JSON encoded string returned properly.

Comment: @Ohmygod Didn't realize that. I get the following from the console: `Object { class: "inactive", body: "whatever you were returning before" }`

Comment: Perfect. Now all you need to do is replace `"inactive"` with a variable return from your PHP script with whatever logic is performed. `"body"` should contain the text/HTML that you wish to work with, so if you return `<h1> This is my return message!</h>` you can simply do, `$('body').append(data.body)` in the `success: function(data){`

Comment: Thanks again - I really appreciate your help. I don't quite understand what exactly I need to do in order to change change the class in the specific link clicked to whatever is returned from get.php?

Comment: @Ypsala Please check my profile and send me an email. We will maintain correspondence there, as this is not a good fit for stack overflow.

Comment: @Ypsala Provide yours, I'll send you one.

Comment: Here you go: ohgodwhy@a6-swim.dk - just a temporary one, so that I don't get overwhelmed by spam..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you should use a JavaScript library like jQuery to help you do this.

```
// bind a click handler to all links that have href starting with get.php
$("a[href^=get.php]").on("click", function(e){
    // prevent link from navigating to get.php
    e.preventDefault();
    // jQuery object of the anchor tag
    var $link = $(this);
    // use Ajax to send data to get.php
    $.getJSON($link.attr("href"), function(data){
        // replace current class with the value in data.class
        $link.removeClass().addClass(data.class);
    });
})
```

get.php should return json data

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'class' => 'new class',
));
```

Comment: Thanks. I must admit that JSON is completely new to me. When I try your code, the link is just sending me to get.php. Is there anything I should change in the code for it to work?